# PHP file_get_contents does not return an error when it should

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using file_get_contents to get the json from URLs. The same URL works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't, file_get_contents does not return any error and just stops the whole script. It's too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

What's error you get? It's warning or Fatal Error?

if it's warning, please add @ to befor file_get_contents like: @file_get_contents
if other, please check data before execute other process

```
$jsondata =@file_get_contents('YOur URl');
if($jsondata){
  // Process your code
}else{
  //do nothing
}
```

Comment: it does not return any error or warning. the script just stops after file_get_contents is called.

Answer (score 0):

What a URL is returning when the correct data is not outputted ?

**1)**

```
 $json_data =file_get_contents('URl');
    if($json_data){
       //parse the data
      }else{
        //show error
     }
```

**2**   to find what exactly the url returns

```
$json_data =file_get_contents('URl');
var_dump($json_data);
```

**3**  use cURL

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url_here');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result);
var_dump($obj)
```

Comment: As I have already said, ANY line of code just after the file_get_contents($url) command does not get executed, even a simple echo 'hi'; statement. And if it helps, the URL input into file_get_contents is perfectly correct because it works sometimes and does not work sometimes.

Comment: @NavkarJain  please use curl and check

Comment: Ok I implemented cURL in the whole process and now its giving less errors but not NO errors. Maybe its just a server memory issue? or too many web service connections at a time? It always returns an error just after about 200 to 250 queries are executed using the web service.

Comment: check you server side how much process or execution he take upto

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It turned out when I print out the HTML data, I could read the retrieved data. But my PHP script stopped right after that without an error message.

Then I realized:
To check the size of the retrieved data, I used

```
$size = str_len($page)
```

instead of

```
strlen($page)
```

Correcting this, again the script stopped rigth behind this line.

Reason then was, I used to search the whole response for a substring with

```
if(str_contains($page, 'Neelde'))
```

But this function was introduced with php 8 while my server was using php v7.6.

So I added

```
if (!function_exists('str_contains')) {
    function str_contains( $haystack, $needle)
    {
        return $needle !== '' && mb_strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false;
    }
}
```

And my script was running corretcly.

So check for any syntax erros behind the file_get_contents(...